# Vim: highlight every Nth line?

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim to write something where "pages" are important. Pages are a fixed number of lines.

I use `:set colorcolumn` to highlight the right margin. Is there anything similar to highlight every Nth line of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution below:

```
function HighlightEvery(lineNumber, lineEnd)
    highlight myhighlightpattern ctermbg=darkred guibg=darkred
    let pattern="/"
    let i = 0
    while i < a:lineEnd
        let i += a:lineNumber
        let pattern .= "\\%" . i . "l\\|"
    endwhile
    let pattern .= "\\%0l/"
    let commandToExecute = "match myhighlightpattern ".pattern
    execute commandToExecute
endfunction

command -nargs=* Highlightevery call HighlightEvery(<f-args>)
```

Add the code above in your .vimrc,

and call

```
:Highlightevery 10 1000
```

will highlight every 10 lines in to line number 1000.

Comment: That worked fine, thanks! Minor detail, vim complains "User defined commands must start with an uppercase letter"

Comment: This is Vim script. (see `:help script`)